# How can I make this C code for checking checksum shorter?

Tags: c

This is a function for checking if the checksum provided by `card[]` is valid. `card[]` contains six pairs of characters. The first five pairs make up a hexadecimal number, and the last pair contains the checksum. The checksum is valid if it is equal to XOR of the first five pairs.

It is working fine, but the code is awful. I was trying to use a nested loop, but it wasn't working. Now I'm getting pairs from `card[]`, converting them into numbers and checking whether the checksum is valid.

```
bool checksum(char card[])
{
int a=0;
char character0[2];
char character1[2];
char character2[2];
char character3[2];
char character4[2];
char character5[2];
long n0,n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
char card_number;

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
        character0[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=2;i<4;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
            character1[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=4;i<6;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
            character2[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=6;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
            character3[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=8;i<10;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
            character4[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    for(int i=10;i<12;i++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<2;a++)
        {
            character5[a]=card[i];
        }
    }
    n0 = strtol(character0, NULL, 16);
    n1 = strtol(character1, NULL, 16);
    n2 = strtol(character2, NULL, 16);
    n3 = strtol(character3, NULL, 16);
    n4 = strtol(character4, NULL, 16);
    n5 = strtol(character5, NULL, 16);


if(n0^n1^n2^n3^n4==n5)     return true;
else return false;


}
```

The input for the example is "1E00EDE5E5F3", so 1E^00^ED^E5^E5 should be F3.

And something is wrong with this code. I see it now, because

```
if(n0^n1^n2^n3^n4==n5)     return true;
else return false;
```

is working good, but

```
if((n0^n1^n2^n3^n4)==n5))     return true;
else return false;
```

is not working at all.

Comment: Obvious nitpick here, but your aim shouldn't be to make it "shorter". It should be to make it "better". I know that's what you mean, but it's always worth pointing out that the two are not necessarily equivalent.

Answer (score 20):

Use a 2D array instead of 6 1D arrays (vs. `character0`, `character1`, ...)

Use a 1D array for `n` instead of (`n0`, `n1`, ...)

Add EOS termination to the string that gets passed to `strtol`

Here's a refactored version:

```
bool
checksum(char card[])
{
    char chars[6][3];
    long nx[6];

    for (int col = 0;  col < 6;  ++col) {
        int lo = col << 1;
        int hi = lo + 2;
        for (int i = lo;  i < hi;  ++i)
            chars[col][i - lo] = card[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0;  i < 6;  ++i) {
        char *ptr = chars[i];
        ptr[2] = 0;
        nx[i] = strtol(ptr,NULL,16);
    }

    if (nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4] == nx[5])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

Here's a cleaner/simpler version:

```
bool
checksum(char card[])
{
    char tmp[3];
    long nx[6];

    tmp[2] = 0;
    for (int col = 0;  col < 6;  ++col) {
        int lo = col << 1;

        tmp[0] = card[lo + 0];
        tmp[1] = card[lo + 1];

        nx[col] = strtol(tmp,NULL,16);
    }

    if (nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4] == nx[5])
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

Here's an even simpler version:

```
bool
checksum(char card[])
{
    char tmp[3];
    long nx;

    tmp[2] = 0;
    nx = 0;
    for (int idx = 0;  idx < 12;  idx += 2) {
        tmp[0] = card[idx + 0];
        tmp[1] = card[idx + 1];

        nx ^= strtol(tmp,NULL,16);
    }

    if (nx == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

---

**UPDATE #3:**

Based on some feedback ...

The first two examples above, were to eliminate "parallel scalar" variables (e.g.) `v0, v1, v2, ... vN` in favor of an array: `v[N+1]`. This allowed replicated code to be replaced with loops. OP's code had two such instances for `character*` and `n*` variables, so I converted both to arrays.

When starting out [as a programmer], when to use an array isn't always obvious [particularly for small numbers]. In the above case, `N` was 6. So, the code could be built up by cut-and-paste.

If, however, `N` had been a much larger number, say, 1000, the original code would then not *scale* well. And, the array solution would have become [more] obvious.

OP's code was trying to copy two bytes from the buffer into different `char` arrays of the form `character*` in the first code block [to add an EOS char to allow `strtol` to work]. This still had a bug because there was no space for the EOS.

OP's second block would use `strtol` on the intermediate `character*` variables to produce `n*` variables.

My first example [in my *original* post], did the conversion from separate scalar variables to arrays.

My second example [in my first update], combined both blocks/loops into one, so that `character*` [which I had replaced with the 2D `chars` array], could be eliminated with a single `tmp` array.

When I did my example in update #2, I assumed that OP's algorithm was correct. I didn't realize that:

```
if (nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4] == nx[5])
```

was being interpreted [by the compiler, based on precedence] as:

```
if (nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ (nx[4] == nx[5]))
```

I assumed it was grouped as:

```
if ((nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4]) == nx[5])
```

Because that's what made sense for the CRC calculations [and I assumed OP had done it correctly].

My refinement [to eliminate the `nx` *array* in favor of a running CRC], was based on the following identity:

```
(x == y) === ((x ^ y) == 0)
```

So, XORing all values (including the checksum), if the message was correct/intact, would produce a final value of zero. So, by doing this, I fixed OP's second bug, based on some serendipity.

Others have pointed out that:

```
if (nx == 0)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Can be replaced with:

```
return (nx == 0);
```

I had debated doing that, but decided that the example was already far afield from OP's original and that it would be clearer to leave the `return` sequence as it was. And, the optimizer would [probably] produce the same exact code for both.

At that point, I had debated coming up with a `hex` function that decoded a single hex char as others have suggested, calling it twice and eliminating the copy to `tmp` and call to `strtol`, but, again, felt I was getting far enough away from the original code.

But, just for the sake of completeness, here is my final/best example, generalized to allow an arbitrary buffer size:

```
unsigned int
hex(unsigned int chr)
{

    // NOTE: hopefully, this function gets inlined ...

    do {
        if ((chr >= '0') && (chr <= '9')) {
            chr -= '0';
            break;
        }

        chr = tolower(chr);

        if ((chr >= 'a') && (chr <= 'f')) {
            chr -= 'a';
            chr += 10;
            break;
        }

        // should blow up here (but there was no error checking in original)
        chr = 0;
    } while (0);

    return chr;
}

bool
checksum(const char *card,size_t len)
{
    unsigned int cur;
    unsigned int crc = 0;

    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < len;  idx += 2) {
        cur = hex(card[idx + 0]);
        cur <<= 4;

        cur |= hex(card[idx + 1]);

        crc ^= cur;
    }

    return (crc == 0);
}
```

Note that even this could be tweaked a bit more for speed with some careful benchmarking ...

---

**UPDATE #4:**

Eliminating the call to `hex` in favor of a [single] table lookup may be faster and provide some error checking:

```
int
checksum(const char *card,size_t len)
{
    static unsigned char hex[256] = { ['0'] = 0xFF };
    unsigned int chr;
    unsigned int cur;
    unsigned int crc = 0;

    // one time init of translation table
    if (hex['0'] == 0xFF) {
        for (chr = 0x00;  chr <= 0xFF;  ++chr)
            hex[chr] = 0xFF;

        for (chr = 0;  chr <= 9;  ++chr)
            hex[chr + '0'] = chr;

        for (chr = 0x00;  chr <= 0x05;  ++chr) {
            hex[chr + 'a'] = chr + 0x0A;
            hex[chr + 'A'] = chr + 0x0A;
        }
    }

    for (size_t idx = 0;  idx < len;  idx += 2) {
        chr = hex[card[idx + 0]];
#ifdef ABORT_ON_ERROR
        if (chr == 0xFF)
            return -1;
#endif
        cur = chr;
        cur <<= 4;

        chr = hex[card[idx + 1]];
#ifdef ABORT_ON_ERROR
        if (chr == 0xFF)
            return -1;
#endif
        cur |= chr;

        crc ^= cur;
    }

    return (crc == 0);
}
```

Comment: In your last code snippet, you can simply `return nx == 0` instead of the `if` statement.

Comment: If I read the [operator precedence chart](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) correctly, `==` has precedence over `^` so that `nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4] == nx[5]` amounts to `nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ (nx[4] == nx[5])`. (The OP suspected as much already.) It is recommended to bracket the more obscure and seldomly used operators. Of course that judgement is in the eye of the beholder: Too many brackets again obscure the code.

Comment: I really like the explanation since it teaches a lot of the mindset of a C programmer.

Comment: In your update #3, you made the typical mistake of passing an illegal value to `tolower`. You must not cast from `char` directly to `unsigned int`, but take the intermediate step of casting from `char` to `unsigned char`. Also you are assuming that the letters `abcdef` are adjacent in the execution character set, which is not guaranteed. ASCII and EBCDIC behave that way, but you can never know. Therefore the `strtol` from the original code was better.

Comment: Update 4 feels like a lot of speculative code for a "may be faster" with no benchmarking.  If I wrote that and then stepped back to look at it, I think I'd stash it away and then test the original to see whether any speedup is required. And if it is, I'd then test this version to see if it was a real improvement ...

Comment: @Useless Yes, to decide between the two, benchmarking would be helpful. From the previous update, I said: _Note that even this could be tweaked a bit more for speed with some careful benchmarking ..._ If the prior example, _inlines_ the `hex` call, it _might_ be faster. But, it's still several instructions per call. The final version, after getting the `hex` _array_ into the cache, is two memory fetches [from cache], so I suspect it would go faster because it's just the two fetches, whereas the `hex` func version has some `if` against the ranges in addition to to the fetch for `tolower`

Comment: @RolandIllig Yes, it is possible that a system is non-ascii (i.e. non-contiguous), but that would be _rare_. I've yet to encounter one (even EBCDIC usually gets translated at the "outer edge"). If it were _truly_ a concern, one could add a diagnostic test at program start to compare both `hex` against `strtol` for all [256] possible combinations, selecting `hex` if it works and fallback to `strtol` if it fails. But, again, this would be rare. I've often written such startup code [sometimes in a utility that is called during the `make` to compile the best algorithm via `#ifdef`].

Comment: And nothing about the indentation?

Comment: @PeterMortensen By that I presume you mean OP's original indentation? That could be an artefact of the code block. But, except for readability here, I don't worry about indentation. For example, before I refactor code here [or on SO], I run the source through a wrapper script that invokes GNU `indent` and it reformats the code, according to _my_ :-) style guide. Indentation and coding style [enforcement] should be automated. So, in a way, I did comment on the indent/style by reformatting it.

Comment: You misunderstand me. I'm saying there is no point writing #4 in the first place, _unless_ you already tested the simple version and found it too slow. You can spend all day coming up with alternative implementations that might be faster, but generally shouldn't unless you have a specific requirement.

Answer (score 8):

The most obvious issue is that you create excessive double loops for the same type of array initialisations.

### Convert similar loops into one

Instead of creating `6` separate double loops for each `character` array, set each array in the same double loop:

```
...
for(int i=0;i<2;i++) {
    for(a=0;a<2;a++) {
        character0[a]=card[i];
        character1[a]=card[i + 2];
        character2[a]=card[i + 4];
        character3[a]=card[i + 6];
        character4[a]=card[i + 8];
        character5[a]=card[i + 10];
    }
}
...
```

This change alone will make your code much shorter and more readable already. IT can be simplified even further - check the answer from @Craig Estey.

### Minor improvements

- Your `char card_number;` is never used so you can simply remove it.
- Declaring `a` outside of your loops is not necessary. You can create it within a `for` loop as `for(int a=0; a<2; a++)`.
- Maybe `n1` or `n2` and so on could have better names but I fail to come up with any.
- As mentioned by @PeterMortensen, indentation in your code should be more consistent. For example, in your loop your `character` array is indented as:

  ```
  for(a=0;a<2;a++)
  {
  character0[a]=card[i];
  }
  ```

  But then in another `for` loop as:

  ```
  for(a=0;a<2;a++)
  {
      character4[a]=card[i];
  }
  ```

  Also, indentation for local variables declaration and `return` statements is different from that of the `for` loops.

Answer (score 5):

I have a recommendation. But first a critique.

The main problem with the program is that it's very badly broken.
You have six loops, none of which is working correctly.

First, if you were to actually write down the steps of your first loop and what part of `card` is copied to `character0` at each step, you should find at the end that the last thing written to `character[0]` is `card[1]` and the last thing written to `character[1]` is `card[1]`. In other words, `character0` ends up containing two copies of `card[1]`, and `card[0]` ends up being ignored.
Likewise `card[2]`, `card[4]`, `card[6]`, `card[8]`, and `card[10]` all will be ignored in your final calculations.

A second serious defect is that you pass a string to `strtol` without putting a null terminator at the end of the string. Therefore you are telling `strtol` to parse the two characters you gave it plus whatever is after them in memory. "Whatever is after" *might* be a null character, which will give you the result you want, or it might be some other non-hexadecimal character, which also will give you the result you want, or it might be one or more hexadecimal characters, which usually will give you a wrong result.
When I tried running your code in an online compiler and gave it the input 112233445566, and inserted `printf("n = %x %x %x %x %x %x\n", n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5);` near the end to see what six numbers it got, the output was

11 2211 332211 44332211 44332211 44332211

This tells me something about how that particular compiler laid out the twelve bytes of memory for `character0` through `character5`.
It also tells me you were asking for undefined behavior when you called your `strtol` functions.
This is basic test and debugging that you should have done before posting here.

There is a third defect, that `n0^n1^n2^n3^n4==n5` does not work the way you meant it to, but you already have realized that this needs to be looked into.

---

Now my recommendation. My main recommendation is to write smaller functions.
You *could* do the whole thing very compactly in one function via loops,
but I recommend smaller functions because small functions force you to think about
what each one is doing by itself: what are the inputs, exactly, what is the output,
what is the task the function has to perform.
If you name your function well, it will even make the code more self-documenting.

A smaller function that seems obvious to me is:

> Take two characters from `card`. Parse them as a hexadecimal number, turning them into an integer in the range 0 to 255, and return that integer.

It's also fairly obvious that you'll end up calling the function six times, due to the way the larger function's specification is written:

> `card[]` contains six pairs of characters. The first five pairs make up a hexadecimal number, the last pair contains the checksum.

Now you just need to figure out how to pass each pair of characters to your function.
For example, if you name the function `convertCharacterPairToNumber` you might pass the second pair like this:

```
convertCharacterPairToNumber(card[2], card[3])
```

Or you might decide to make your function aware of `card` but tell it which two characters to use:

```
convertCharacterPairToNumber(card, 2, 3)
```

Or you might realize that the second character is always right after the first one, so you just need to tell your function where the first character is:

```
convertCharacterPairToNumber(card, 2)
```

Or you might decide that a pointer into the string, pointing at the first of the two characters in the pair, is enough:

```
convertCharacterPairToNumber(&card[2])
```

Then you just need to write the function's implementation and test it before you put it into the larger function.
You could solve two of the three major defects in your program this way.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of calling `strtol` repeatedly, you could also call it once to extract a 64-bit integer, and then do some calculations on that integer.

The basic idea is:

```c
bool checksum(const char *card) {

    unsigned long long int num = strtoull(card, NULL, 16);

    unsigned long long int xored = 0;

    xored ^= num >> 40;
    xored ^= num >> 32;
    xored ^= num >> 24;
    xored ^= num >> 16;
    xored ^= num >> 8;
    xored ^= num;

    return (xored & 0xFF) == 0;
}
```

The above code works by looking at a small "window" of the number in each line. One after another, the digit pairs are shifted into that "window" and xored to form the final result. It basically looks like this:

```
AABBCCDDEEFF   <- the number
00AABBCCDDEE   <- the number, shifted by 8 bits to the right
        00AA   <- the number, shifted by 40 bits to the right

          **
          AABBCCDDEEFF    40 bits
        AABBCCDDEEFF      32 bits
      AABBCCDDEEFF        24 bits
    AABBCCDDEEFF          16 bits
  AABBCCDDEEFF             8 bits
AABBCCDDEEFF               0 bits
          **
```

The small part between the asterisks is the interesting part of the "window", which will form the final result. Outside this window, the bits also take part in the computation, but they will be ignored. The nice thing about xor is that the outside bits cannot influence the inside bits. This is different from the usual integer addition or subtraction.

After xoring all the shifted numbers, the interesting part of the window is extracted using `& 0xFF`. In the first attempt I used an `unsigned char xored`, but then I realized that it might be larger than 8 bits. It seemed clever at first but really wasn't. I could have used `uint8_t`, which would have worked as well. Which one is better depends on the generated machine code. When you have learned assembler, you can look at the generated code and compare them.

What's left now is some error checking. Your code silently assumes that it will only be passed valid data, that is a 12-digit hex number. It's not that difficult to add the missing error handling:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

bool checksum(const char *card) {
    if (strlen(card) != 12) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure that the whole card number looks like a hex number.
    char *end;
    unsigned long long int num = strtoull(card, &end, 16);
    if (end != card + 12) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure the first character is not a space or hyphen or plus,
    // which would be accepted by strtoull.
    if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)card[0])) {
        return false;
    }

    // Make sure the second character is not an x, since 0x would be
    // interpreted as "hex" by strtoull.
    if (!isxdigit((unsigned char)card[1])) {
        return false;
    }

    unsigned long long int xored = 0;

    xored ^= num >> 40;
    xored ^= num >> 32;
    xored ^= num >> 24;
    xored ^= num >> 16;
    xored ^= num >> 8;
    xored ^= num;

    return (xored & 0xFF) == 0;
}
```

To be sure that the above code is correct, you must think of a whole bunch of test cases. One test case is definitely not enough since a simple `return true` would have made that test succeed.

A few test cases I came up with are:

```
#include <assert.h>

int main(void) {
    assert(checksum("") == false);
    assert(checksum("00000000000") == false); // 11 digits are too short
    assert(checksum("000000000000") == true);
    assert(checksum("0000000000000") == false); // 13 digits are too long
    assert(checksum("000000000001") == false);
    assert(checksum("000000000101") == true);
    assert(checksum("000000010001") == true);
    assert(checksum("000001000001") == true);
    assert(checksum("000100000001") == true);
    assert(checksum("010000000001") == true);
    assert(checksum("FF01020408F0") == true);
    assert(checksum("123456563412") == true);
    assert(checksum("123456654321") == false);
    assert(checksum("abcdefABCDEF") == true);
    assert(checksum("abcdefABCDEF") == true);
    assert(checksum("abcdegABCDEF") == false); // invalid character in the middle
    assert(checksum("-00000000000") == false); // invalid character at the beginning
    assert(checksum("           0") == false); // invalid character at the beginning
    assert(checksum("+00000000000") == false); // invalid character at the beginning
    assert(checksum("0x0000000000") == false); // don't let strtoull trick us with hex

    assert(checksum("1E00EDE5E5F3") == true);
}
```

I intentionally used the `== true` and `== false` here to keep the beginnings of the lines the same, to make them clearly stick out as a block of code. If I had used the often recommended form of omitting the `== true` and replacing `x == false` with `!x`, the visual code layout would have been much more chaotic.

Answer (score 3):

It would be interesting to eliminate the loops;  I suspect the optimizer will deal with the hard coded indexes and optimize the code.

```
character0[0]=card[0];
character1[0]=card[2];
character2[0]=card[4];
character3[0]=card[6];
character4[0]=card[8];
character5[0]=card[10];
character0[0]=card[1];
character1[0]=card[3];
character2[0]=card[5];
character3[0]=card[7];
character4[0]=card[9];
character5[0]=card[11];
character0[1]=card[0];
character1[1]=card[2];
character2[1]=card[4];
character3[1]=card[6];
character4[1]=card[8];
character5[1]=card[10];
character0[1]=card[1];
character1[1]=card[3];
character2[1]=card[5];
character3[1]=card[7];
character4[1]=card[9];
character5[1]=card[11];
```

Comment: The compiler will likely leave it. Even though it's ugly, this type of code is performant.

Comment: I find this version to be easier to read, reason about, and debug as well.

Comment: This does exactly what the largest part of the original program does (up to the first strtol). Now observe that you can delete lines 1-6 and lines 13-18 without changing the results.

Comment: What's up with all the re-assignment nonsense? (e.g., `character0[0]=card[0];` on line 1, and then `character0[0]=card[1];` on line 7?)

Comment: @will I agree, After taking a look at the entire code rather than focusing on the loops this code could get rid of reassignments.

Comment: Since a decent compiler is perfectly capable of unrolling constant loops itself, I'm not sure what this answer is trying to achieve. Anyway, manual unrolling is pretty much never used to make the code _better_, but to make it worse-and-faster where that tradeoff is justified.

Comment: @Useless by unrolling the code manually it's easier to see that half of the assignments are useless and can be removed. After that, the loops can be added again.

Answer (score 3):

You have several answers showing alternative solutions, or describing what's wrong with your existing code. I'm going to try to show how I'd get from *here* (your current code) to something I'd actually be happy using.

### 1. The Declaration

```
bool checksum(char card[])
```

is already kind of a problem. There's no way to communicate to the caller that conversion failed. This might be OK if it's only used inside a module that already guarantees our pre-requisites, but we should at least say very clearly what they are.

The function name actually isn't great either, because a *checksum* is a noun, which means this function sounds like it should calculate and return one of those.

I'm using Doxygen markdown just to get in the mood of writing real code.

```
/**
 * Validate a checksummed card number.
 * The format is 12 hex digits, with the last two representing
 * a single-octet checksum of the first 10 chars/5 octets.
 *
 * @param card must contain 12 hex digits.
 *
 * @note This function will not check for short (or NULL)
 * arguments and will not gracefully handle invalid digits.
 *
 * @return true if the input is valid
 */
bool validate_checksum(const char *card)
```

### 2. The Repetition

You have five identical loops populating five variables with numbers in their names - this should always *always* be factored out somehow. Variables with numbers in their names (ordinal numbers, rather than say `point3d`) are a particular red flag - they should either be an array, or a loop.

Even when we know we should move the repeated code into a function, it isn't always obvious how best to structure it. One approach is to work backwards from the desired result, and see how to get *there*.

### 2.a The End Result

We want something equivalent to the expression

```
return (b0 ^ b1 ^ b2 ^ b3 ^ b4 ^ b5) == 0;
```

(note that if `b0 ^ ... ^ b4 == b5` then `b0 ^ ... ^ b4 ^ b5` must be zero, and grouping all the input values together makes it easy to naturally avoid the operator precedence problem in your original code)

... but ideally without those numbered variables I called out earlier. We don't really need to keep all six values around at one time either, so we could write

```
unsigned long result = 0;
/* 5 is NUM_OCTETS_IN_CARD or similar */
for (int octnum = 0; octnum < 6; ++octnum)
{
    result ^= hex_octet(card);
    card += 2;
    /* 2 is CHARS_PER_OCTET */
}
return result == 0;
```

I made a note of things that should probably be clearly-defined constants instead of magic numbers, but I'm not writing the whole program here.

### 2.b The Repetition pt.2

Now we know what we want the interface to our factored-out code to look like, it's easier to write:

```
/**
 * Convert two hexadecimal characters to an integer.
 * The parameter must point to a string with at least two valid
 * hex characters.
 */
unsigned long hex_octet(const char *o)
{
    char tmp[3] = { o[0], o[1], 0 };
    return strtoul(tmp, NULL, 16);
}
```

Note that the only reason for using `unsigned long` above was to avoid extra work converting from `strtoul` - otherwise we could have just used `uint8_t` for the octet values.

Writing our own hex conversion is certainly feasible, but not immediately necessary. If lots of (well, six) calls to `strtoul` look expensive during profiling, it might be less work to replace them with a single call to `strtoull` returning all six octets in a single `unsigned long long`, and then work on the low six bytes of that (the minimum allowed size for `unsigned long` is 32 bits or 4 bytes, which isn't enough).

After all that, we should have something that works up to the constraints we imposed on the input.

### 3. Interface Improvements

We could actually check our pre-requisites, either just with

```
assert(isxdigit(c)==0)
```

for every character, or perhaps with

```
char *end;
unsigned long long whole = strtoull(card, &end, 16);
assert(end == card+12);
```

if `card` is guaranteed to be null-terminated.

Either way, if we don't want to just abort (in debug builds, and continue blithely on in release builds), we need a different interface to tell the caller about errors. With all those constants I mentioned earlier, and proper error-checking, we might end up with

```
/**
 * Validate a checksummed card number.
 * The format is 12 hex digits, representing 6 octets.
 * The last octet is a checksum for the first five.
 *
 * @param card must contain 12 hex digits. If it is not null-terminated, only the
 * first 12 digits are used.
 *
 * @return 0 (zero) if the checksum is correct, or
 *         a positive integer if the checksum is incorrect
 *         a negative integer if the input format is invalid
 */
int validate_checksum(const char *card)
{
    static const int BITS_PER_OCTET = 8;
    static const unsigned long long LOW_OCTET_MASK = 0xFF;
    static const int CHARS_PER_OCTET = 2;
    static const int EXPECTED_OCTETS = 6;
    static const int EXPECTED_CHARS = EXPECTED_OCTETS * CHARS_PER_OCTET;

    char tmp[EXPECTED_CHARS + 1];
    memcpy(tmp, card, EXPECTED_CHARS);
    tmp[EXPECTED_CHARS] = 0;

    char *end;
    unsigned long long value = strtoull(tmp, &end, 16);
    if (end != tmp + EXPECTED_CHARS)
    {
        /* error: got (end-tmp) hex digits instead of EXPECTED_CHARS */
        return -1;   
    }

    uint8_t octet = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < EXPECTED_OCTETS; ++i)
    {
        octet ^= (uint8_t)(value & LOW_OCTET_MASK);
        value >>= BITS_PER_OCTET;
    }

    return octet; /* zero is correct, non-zero must be +ve */
}
```

Things like `BITS_PER_OCTET` are probably overkill when "octet" literally means "eight bits", but I decided to eliminate magic numbers from the code almost entirely. Conversely, the integer constant `0xFF` could have been written `(1 << BITS_PER_OCTET) - 1`, but I'm used to reading this sort of value in hex - YMMV.

Comment: Fixed the off-by-one. The low octet mask is already addressed in the text, and the `CHARS_PER_OCTET` change really suggests _another_ constant, `BITS_PER_CHAR = 4` or something. I generally prefer masking explicitly, it's easier to reason about in general.

Answer (score 3):

The majority of your function consists of parsing a string of 12 characters into six numbers, expecting that each number is represented as a two-digit hexadecimal value in the input string. This is unfortunate, since it obfuscates the core of this function - the algorithm by which the checksum is computed!

Luckily, this kind of parsing is so common that there's a ready-made function in the standard library for this task, called [`sscanf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/). Reusing `sscanf` instead of doing your own parsing also does away with any bugs you may have introduced, so your perfectly reasonable expectation of

```
if((n0^n1^n2^n3^n4)==n5))   return true; 
else return false;
```

working should be met.

Lastly, you might like to consider a stylistic adjustment and eliminate the unneeded `if` statement, given that for some expression `e`, the code

```
if (e) return true;
else return false;
```

is equivalent to

```
return e;
```

Thus, you could shorten your function to

```c
bool checksum(char card[])
{
    unsigned n0, n1, n2, n3, n4, n5;
    int num_fields_converted;

    num_fields_converted = sscanf(card, "%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X%02X", &n0, &n1, &n2, &n3, &n4, &n5);

    assert(num_fields_converted == 6 || !"Input string malformed");

    return (n0 ^ n1 ^ n2 ^ n3 ^ n4) == n5;
}
```

This nicely emphasises the actual way by which the `checksum` function computes its output value: it XOR's the first five bytes and then verifies that this equals the sixth byte.

Note that this assumes (by checking the `sscanf` return value) that the input string is well-formed before bothering to verify the checksum. Instead of using an `assert`, some other behaviour might be more convenient in your use case (e.g. returning `false`).

Comment: Of course, when using `scanf()` family of functions, we always check the return value.  Don't we?

Comment: @TobySpeight It depends: in case `sscanf` fails, how should `checksum` behave? After all, it cannot even compute the checksum, so how could it test if the checksum matches. You could set e.g. a global error code, but it's not far-fetched to just document the function as being undefined for malformed inputs. Partial functions are tricky though, a good fix might be to have some `assert`ions or maybe a dedicated type (instead of `char*`) which expresses the preconditions explicitly (and moves the input validation to the caller).

Comment: That's a good question, and when I'm writing code that's a time to go back to the customer and ask what they want to happen.  Most likely, we should return `false` if we can't read or can't parse the string; other possibilities include changing the functions return type to be able to express more than boolean (e.g. use an int or enum).

Comment: I think what Toby wanted to say politely is: We expect _every_ answer on Code Review to either _use and check_ the return value of `scanf`, or alternatively give a very good reason why the return value does not need to be checked. Silently ignoring the return value is questionable.

Comment: @RolandIllig That makes perfect sense; I now added `assert`ions to express the preconditions of the function (not satisfying them renders the behaviour undefined).

Answer (score 1):

As `x ^ x == 0` on can do a homogeneous:

```
return nx[0] ^ nx[1] ^ nx[2] ^ nx[3] ^ nx[4] ^ nx[5] == 0;
```

A char, a hex digit represent a nibble, 4 bits. As XORing does not influence other positions (like ADDing), one can do the checksum separately on the two nibbles:

```
int
hex(char ch)
{
    // For ASCII
    return ch <= '9' ? (int) ch - '0' : (ch & 0xF) + 9;
}
```

The hex function should give a number 0 <= x < 16 for characters 0-9A-Fa-f, for ASCII based character encodings.

***After feedback to the non-validating hex function:***

```
int
hex(char ch)
{
    char* digits = "0123456789ABCDEFabcdef";
    char* p = strchr(digits, ch);
    if (!p) {
        return -1;
    }
    int digit = p - digits;
    return digit < 16 ? digit : digit - 6;
}
```

One might do more than returning -1. Or check it at the call site.

```
bool
checksum_valid(char* card)
{
    if (strlen(card) != 6*2) {
        return false;
    }
    int crc0 = 0;
    int crc1 = 0;
    while (*card) {
        crc0 ^= hex(*card++);
        crc1 ^= hex(*card++);
    }
    return crc0 == 0 && crc1 == 0;
}
```

Using `0 ^ x == x` and `x ^ x == 0`.

Comment: While your answer isn't code only, it doesn't really review the original posters code. Good answers on code review review the code and don't necessarily provide an alternate solution at all.

Comment: @pacmaninbw thanks, that explains to me not receiving points ;). After the review of the return statement of the OP, "making the answer shorter" went to an entire removal of the extra array and so on. I leave the answer for who it wants to use,

Comment: Letters are not guaranteed by the standard to be contiguous. You'll probably have to use a lookup table for it.

Comment: @S.S.Anne yes EBCDIC is such a case. I assumed ASCII however. A `strchr` or such is nicer though. And allows to validate that the characters are valid hex digits.

Comment: `ch <= '9'` will do bad stuff for `ch < '0'`.

Comment: @S.S.Anne no validation. I'll rewite the hex function.

Comment: Nice `strchr` solution.

Comment: `strchr(digits, tolower(ch))` would be better, especially as the sample input from the OP uses upper case.